# Is this grammatically correct "was and continues to be doing something"?

Tags: compounds, predicate

I'm confused by the construction "the team **was** and **continues** ***to be*** **doing** something".

I'd simply say "the team **has been** doing something". But the sentence is meant to point out the *persistence* of doing an action.

Should the original construction be corrected to say "the team **was and continues doing** something"?

Comment: I edited your question to make it clearer, but I wasn't sure if you made a mistake in the final sentence or not. Did you mean to type *and continues doing something* or *and continues **to be** doing something*?

Comment: Thanks for editing. In the last sentence, I meant to type *continues doing something*

Comment: Great. I made a further correction. Feel free to rephrase anything I got wrong.

Comment: Without knowing what the 'something' is it's hard to be certain, but I imagine it is intended to emphasise the fact that the activity has been going on for some time and still is.

Comment: The "was and continues" version brings to mind a scenario where the speaker is defending against criticism. For example, "why wasn't your team doing something about it?" It emphasizes both that something has been in progress both at some point in the past, and that it also continues to be done. But if such emphasis is unwarranted, then "the team has been doing something" is the more straightforward way to express it.

Comment: The construction wasn't meant to defend against criticism but rather to praise the team. The original "the team was and continues to be contributing to building professional journalism in our country" sound clunky to me.

Comment: **The team was contributing to building professional journalism in our country—and continues to do so**.  Had you specified what was being built, it would have been easier to help you. [used to do business journalism]. An em dash properly used can improve a text.

Answer (score -1):

- the team **was and continues to be winning**
  OR
- the team was winning and continues to win
  OR
- The team **was winning** and **continues winning**

That is the **formal** construction here.

The original could use some improvement. The "to be doing" is somewhat clunky. A simpler sentence such as the one I provided is better.

Another example:

- He was going to his tennis lessons and **continues to go** to them.
  OR
  and **continues going to them**.

This type of construction is used for rhetorical emphasis.

Yes, your corrected version is better.

Now that we know what this was about, using an em dash, can clear up confusion:

**The team was contributing to building professional journalism in our country—and continues to do so.**

Context is very important and should have been provided in the question.

Comment: I don't find that adding "right" is necessary to make better sense.

Comment: Tsk, tsk downvoter.